# Confirm for Linkbutton before performing delete in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a delete Linkbutton in my asp.net form. When the user clicks the button it will delete the contents from my db, which has been coded in the OnClick() of the button. But before that I need to have a confirm box which has yes or no options. How do I go about the deletion if the user clicks on "yes" and restrict deletion if user clicks on "no"? My problem is that onclick and onclientclick do not work together. Please help me ..Here is the sample code..

Where do I place the following script?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
```

Code Behind:

```c#
protected void Mark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a.Delete(name);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following code:

```
OnclientClick="return Confirm()"
```

Return true/false from `Confirm()` function, if Confirm() return true then postback will happen otherwise not.

[Refer online sample to test this](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_linkbutton_onclientclick.asp)

Note:
We have used Confirm() in upper case because post has user defined function Confirm(). so please don't confuse with inbuilt function confirm() of java script.

Comment: hi.. Is it applicable for linkbutton?

Comment: Sorry I am new to everything.. Hence the delay!!

Comment: It looks like you need a lowercase c on confirm, OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?');"

Comment: @RichardEdwards Confirm() is user defined function in the Post. Confirm() function signature is in the same manner.

Comment: @Romil My mistake, I thought you were referring to javascript confirm

Comment: upvoted the answer with Confirm lower case as should be. Upper case didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

use OnClientClick="return confirm()"