# GridView Delete with bootbox.confirm always returning false

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, aspxgridview, bootbox

I'm trying to delete a record from a Gridview using a LinkButton inside a TemplateField. My LinkButton should open a bootbox.confirm() and based on the return value do a call to the GridView.RowCommand handler in the backend.

**GridView Layout:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEntRelationship" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataKeyNames="OFTID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataEntRelations" EnableModelValidation="True" >`
   <Columns>
     <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
     <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelRel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Del" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return OpenDeleteBox(this);"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function OpenDeleteBox(sender) {
            bootbox.confirm("Delete This?", function (confirmed) {
                if (confirmed) {
                    alert('if');
                    return true;
                }
            });
            alert('outside');
            return false;         
        }
```

I'm using the OnClientClick to call the javascript function. When inside function, I see the alert('outside') **(implying it already returns false)**  and then the bootbox shows up. If I move the return false into an else clause like:

```
 bootbox.confirm("Delete This?", function (confirmed) {
                if (confirmed) {
                    alert('in if');
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

It goes ahead and deletes the record using the GridView.RowCommand handler without waiting for the confirmbox to even show up.

**EDIT: seemed to do the job**

```
function OpenDeleteBox(sender) {
            if ($(sender).attr("confirmed") == "true") { return true; }
            bootbox.confirm("Delete This?", function (confirmed) {
                if (confirmed) {
                    $(sender).attr("confirmed", confirmed);
                    sender.click();
                }
            });

            return false;

        }
```

Comment: This is covered in the [Documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-notes) - Bootstrap (and therefore Bootbox) modals are asynchronous, so your OnClientClick is going to resolve before the dialog is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these posts.

[OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete');"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831178/onclientclick-return-confirmare-you-sure-you-want-delete)

[Confirm for Linkbutton before performing delete in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700288/confirm-for-linkbutton-before-performing-delete-in-asp-net?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I think you need to use default javascript confirm function with LinkButton. Seems bootbox confirm cannot be used. It's the default behavior.

Comment: I see. that would seem to make sense. I was thinking of doing a manual Ajax postback to the handler for a specific row. Any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: I also found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912017/bootbox-confirm-return-client-result-in-order-to-do-postback-to-rowcommand/30914150